# Prononciation de « Van der Hogen » en français

Tags: prononciation, néerlandais

Dans le nom « Van der Hogen », « van » devrait être prononcé \vɑ̃\ ou  \van\ ([orthodidacte](https://dictionnaire.orthodidacte.com/article/prononciation-van-gogh)).

« en » doit presque certainement être \ɛn\.  ([Roger_Vandenberghe](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roger_Vandenberghe))

Il manque la prononciation de g, qui doit être \g\ en néerlandais.

Comment doit-on prononcer ce nom ?

\vɑ̃ dɛʁ oɡɛn\ ou \vɑ̃ dɛʁ oʒɛn\ ?

Comment: vɑ̃ dɛʁ ogen , avec des g comme dans "Vincent van Gogh" (ou comme "goût" et non "joue"). Même chose pour [van Dongen](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kees_van_Dongen)

Comment: @Graffito Comme ce personnage est français, je crois que cette prononciation bien française (sauf peut-être pour le « ge ») sera parfaite. J'ai oublié de préciser dans ma question que c'est le nom d'un personnage qui est établi en France (Courteline, _Les rond-de-cuir_).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La "meilleure" prononciation est celle que l'on entendra le plus souvent en Belgique, /vandœro:gœn/ ou encore mieux /vandœro:ɣœn/ (Le *G* étant alors prononcé un peu comme la jota espagnole ou le *CH* écossais le *loch*).

Ce /ɣ/ n'existant pas dans la phonologie du français, on le remplace soit par un /ʁ/ ou un /h/ pour en rester proche, soit par un /g/.

*Van* sera compris qu'il soit prononcé /van/ ou /vɑ̃/. Cette dernière prononciation pourra faire sourire en Belgique.

Voici la prononciation originale, probablement surprenante à qui ne connait pas le néerlandais, de *[Van Gogh](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AjSb2CSoT8&t=444s)*.

Comment: La prononciation belge à laquelle je m'attendrais est /vandœro:gœn/, avec les /ə/ néerlandais empruntés par un [œ] stable qu'on pourrait analyser aussi bien comme /ə/ que comme /œ/.

Comment: @Eauquidort Oui, le *R* est bien sûr roulé et les voyelles plus centrales/frontales. Merci !